# ASP.NET route issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have the following in my RouteConfig.cs file

```
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Home Controller has the following:

```
[Route("NewIncident")]
public ActionResult NewIncident()
{
    var viewModel = new IncidentFormViewModel();
    viewModel.NextPage = 2;
    return View("NewIncident",viewModel);
}

[Route("EditIncident/{id?}")]
public ActionResult EditIncident(int? id)
{
    return View("EditIncidentPage" + id);
}

[Route("SaveIncident")]
public ActionResult SaveIncident(IncidentFormViewModel incidentviewmodel)
{

    return RedirectToAction("EditIncident/" + incidentviewmodel.NextPage);
}
```

From my index view, I can click a button that has the @Html.ActionLink as follows:

```
@Html.ActionLink("New Incident", "NewIncident", "Home", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
```

I access the site at `http://sitename/`  and it loads my index page.  I can click the New Incident button and it loads `http://sitename/NewIncident` just fine, but when I click the Save button on the New Incident form, it calls the SaveIncident function just fine, but when it hits the `return RedirectToAction("EditIncident/" + incidentviewmodel.NextPage);` it sends me to `http://sitename/Home/EditIncident/2` instead of just `http://sitename/EditIncident/2`.

Any idea why its adding the `/Home` in there?

Comment: "it sends me to `http://sitename/Home/EditIncident/2` instead of just `http://sitename/Home/EditIncident/2`" These look identical. What were you trying to say?

Comment: It adds the `/Home` in front of the `/EditIncident/2`.

But when I click NewIncident button from the Index view, it sends me to the `NewIncident` action which also lives inside the `HomeController`, but does not add the `/Home` in front of it.

Comment: edited to reflect typo correction to pathname

Comment: No need to tell me! Just fix it. I'm deleting my comments before long.

Answer (score 0):

The parts of the URL are `http://sitename/Controller/Action/Parameter`.

Your `EditIncident` ActionResult lives inside your `Home` Controller, and so you will therefore always see `Home`in front of `EditIncident`.

When you redirect to another Action, you can specify which controller to look for the ActionResult in with `RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName")`. If no Controller is specified, it assumes you want to use the same controller that you are currently in.

Answer (score 0):

yes, Tot Zam are ok, and you need to create an action result method on your controller, this should be bind with a view

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.

Apparently I need to use `Redirect()`, not `RedirectToAction()` for my purposes.

Once I changed this, it rendered the correct URL without adding `/Home` to it